# What is cordova.xml for in Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

While trying to debug a Phonegap error message ("Call to OpenGL ES api with no current context" which doesn't appear to be causing any problems), I came across a newer version of the cordova.xml file which ships with PhoneGap 1.6 and has the following line in it:

```
<preference name="classicRender" value="true" />
```

Adding this line to *my* copy of cordova.xml didn't do anything. But then I also noticed the comments and other lines in that file regarding access origins, and I noticed that my app has the access origin set to 127.0.0.1 but all my code is on a remote server, and this doesn't seem to matter.

I searched for documentation but didn't find any.

So I have to ask: what is the cordova.xml file for, what directives can be put in it, and what are they supposed to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The cordova.xml file is a configuration file that specifies settings for whitelisted urls, log level, and rendering. The file was previously called phonegap.xml and was renamed when Adobe/Nitobi [donated the PhoneGap codebase](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/) to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) for incubation.

The file includes three settings.

First is:

```
<access origin>
```

which specifies an approved list of URLs that can be loaded. These urls are added to the whitelist cache in the [DroidGap](http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/DroidGap.java) class. Only URLs on the whitelist can be loaded in the Cordova webview or a new browser instance.

Second is:

```
<log level>
```

which specifies log level for debugging on Android . It can be set to ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG or VERBOSE (default=ERROR).

Third is:

```
<preference name="classicRender" />
```

which sets the field

```
private boolean classicRender;
```

in the [DroidGap](http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/DroidGap.java;) class. The only reference to what it actually does that I can find is in [this commit](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-callback-commits/201201.mbox/%3C20120106235242.139215318F@tyr.zones.apache.org%3E) to Cordova:

```
   if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14 && this.classicRender)
     {
         //This hack fixes legacy PhoneGap apps
         //We should be using real pixels, not pretend pixels
   ...
```

Perhaps it's more useful to know that it's apparently being [removed](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-callback-commits/201201.mbox/%3C20120125194403.2F9FB3199AF@tyr.zones.apache.org%3E) since it doesn't work properly.

The cordova.xml is parsed in the [DroidGap](http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/DroidGap.java;) class, in the loadConfiguration() method:

```
private void loadConfiguration() {
     int id = getResources().getIdentifier("cordova", "xml", getPackageName());
     ...
     XmlResourceParser xml = getResources().getXml(id);
     etc...
```

See line 1252 in the [DroidGap](http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/DroidGap.java;h=539329e10a1baeff6702e38cf2cae1dc93a53d6c;hb=664a061d#l1243) class for full loadConfiguration() method. All three attributes are parsed but as per above link it appears the classicRender setting doesn't work and can be ignored.